# How to make composer to use an exact SHA1 value?

Tags: git, composer-php

I want to make sure composer is using an exact version of a git repository by specifing the SHA1 of the commit. How can I do this?

I tried just putting the sha1 code into the version string, but this does not work:

```
 [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
 Could not parse version constraint a93cbe224a6922f181f55c7a35bde0cf61a6a5a4
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can specify it after the version, as such (assuming you want the master branch): `"dev-master#a93cbe224"`

Read more about requirements in the [composer docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)

Comment: Does this still work? I can't install this: `{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/support": "4.1.*",
        "mikemclin/wp-password": "dev-master#68b68ca"
    }
}` (`mikemclin/wp-password` dev-master requires `illuminate/support` 4.2, but it is 4.1 at [68b68ca](https://github.com/mikemclin/laravel-wp-password/blob/68b68ca1593411a6c51974f194fac9f6665cb2ca/composer.json))

Comment: See the blue note at https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links (scroll down a bit), it explains why this doesn't work. It's just a technical limitation of the #sha1 feature.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, those little notes we always forget to read :) So we need to create a branch at that commit (or fork the repo if we do not have access to it) if `composer.json` of the package has changed since that commit for now?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much the only way. Ideally though you'd have older tags to rely on in most cases but not everyone tags before doing big changes unfortunately.

Comment: What if you don't want the master branch but let's say 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal stuff, you can do things like this, if you want to pin to a specific release:

```
composer require --dev drupal/rules:8.3.x-dev#f089923e84fdbc81f4101a684a3f1418ff1da51e
```

The `-unstableN` style Drupal tags are not available on packagist.